# grep кол-ва совпадений в конкретных файлах

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Что нужно: грепнуть все файлы в директории и указать кол-во совпадений в каждом файле.
Если искать в 1 файле, я просто пишу
`grep -o 'найти' /home/file | wc -l` 
Если несколько файлов
`grep -rn 'найти' /home/` - выведет совпадения во всех файлах в директории.
Но мне нужно, что бы показало кол-во совпадений в каждом конкретном файле. Тк в нужной мне директории у многих файлов есть нужное совпадение, и нужно узнать где больше 1

Comment: опцию `-c` добавьте при вызове программы *grep* (см. `$ man grep`)

Comment: Ну вот, я придумал такую команду `grep -rH DAEMON /etc/init.d | cut -d: -f 1 | uniq -c`

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться `find` с опцией `exec`:

```bsh
find /home/ -exec grep -cH 'найти' {} \;
```